# Saving a blob to disk in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, blob

I have a blob saved in my database (a text file). I can retrieve this and then use echo on the return value which prints the text file contents. However, I really am not sure how to save the file to disk

`header("content-type: file/txt");`

This seems to save the current php file to disk so I am guessing i need to modify this somehow to work with my blob? Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Save to disk on the server or send as a download to the client

Comment: Do you mean save  the file server-side or download client-side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=blob.txt');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
readfile('...path to your file');
```

or

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=blob.txt');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
echo $blob;
```

That should force a download to the client.

Comment: how do i no the path to the file if the only data i have is a php variable containing the blob?

Comment: you don't need a path to the file, just echo the contents of the blob (second approach) after you've set the header. It should then prompt the user to download the file.

Comment: that just downloads the current php page ;)

Comment: @SkyR you mean the source code? Or are you just being prompted to download a file with the PHP's script filename? The **contents** of the file, independently of filename, should be your blob.

Comment: it saves the html version of the page

Comment: You need to be setting the content-disposition header.  AKA my answer below.  It's what tells the browser "oh, the name to save it as is actually test.txt"

Comment: Answer updated to set content-disposition header and provide a name for file being downloaded

Comment: hmmm the contents are still the html of my page though :/

Comment: @SkyR you should not `echo` the contents of your blob in the same file you use to display your HTML. Create a PHP script file solely to do this task, otherwise the HTML will get appended to your blob contents.

Answer (score 0):

header('content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt');

Change the test.txt to the file's name